# Optimization problem in microeconomic (utility)

Tags: derivatives, optimization

In real life, social comparisons often serve as reference points. Sometimes we use these comparisons as
a way to motivate ourselves. Imagine a situation where two agents exert effort to produce outputs ci, where i $\epsilon$ {1,2}. The output depends on the exerted effort $e_i$ and agent’s ability $a_i$
in the following way $_ = __$
. Each agent’s utility depends on the outcome $c_i$ as well as how this outcome compares to some
reference point $r_i$
: $u_i$ = ln($c_i$ + ($c_i$ − $r_i$
)), with  ≥ 0. Each agent may set a goal outcome $g_i$
for themselves. Exerting effort is costly with the cost function being equal to f()=$\ln\bigl(\frac{b}{{g_i}^{0.5} +(1-e_i)^{0.5}})$

- Question

Assume that both agents are rational, i.e.  = 0. Assume that each agent
simultaneously chooses the optimal output level  and the optimal goal $g_i$
. Write down their
overall utility function taking into account the costs of effort. Compute the optimal level of
output $c_i^{*}$
for each agent and the optimal goal $g_i^{*}$

Comment: You write "assume that both agents rational, i.e. =0", what is supposed to be equal to zero exactly?

Comment: Hello, on my screnn I can see i.e.  = 0.